# Potential - Content Management System

Tags: content-management-system

We are looking for an elegant content management system (CMS). It should be easy to integrate with AAD and should be accessible to both internal and external (non-Microsoft) partners, Role based access control (as certain pages are available only based on persona), rich API support, Version control and should be easy to customize like create forms or pages.

We are currently considering the below options. However, before we dig deeper, reaching out to see if someone has done this.

·  RedTiger 
·  MS Docs 
·  Wiki 
·  Umbraco 
·  SharePoint 
·  PowerApp 
·  WordPress 
·  APIM 2.0 (We are currently using APIM 1.0, and are experiencing challenges due to custom coding here)

If you have a CMS platform that is working for your team, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco is good to start because it's easy to use, quick implementation but if your data grows very fast you should consider to manage it yourself, in this case Umbraco is just like a authentication and role management system.

Hope it help.